# Background image dissapeared html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I'm wrote this for school.

All of a sudden my background image disappeared and I have no idea what the problem is!

The background image is `gradient-bg.jpg` and in the same directory as the header image.

What am I overlooking?

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title> 
            Laboration 1 av Emil
        </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/stilmall.css"  />

</head>

<body id="backnd">

        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="header">
                <h1 class="title">Musikbaren</h1>
            </div>


            <article id="content" style="float:left">
            <h2 class="Rubrik">Detta är en rubrik</h2><hr/>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut porta tristique faucibus. Cras id faucibus massa, vitae scelerisque dui. Vivamus sollicitudin arcu arcu, a cursus risus efficitur non. Pellentesque quis nisl a erat tempus scelerisque eu nec sapien. Aliquam nec mauris iaculis, varius tellus ac, sagittis dui.

            </article>
            <nav id="navbar" style="float:right">

                <ul class="button-group">

                    <LI class="button"><a href="#" >Meny 1</a></LI>
                    <LI class="button"><a href="#" >Meny 1</a></LI>
                    <LI class="button"><a href="#" >Meny 1</a></LI>

                </ul>

            </nav>
            <footer id="footer" style="text-align: center;">
            Här skrivs kontaktuppgifter!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            </footer>

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS-file:

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    border-top-left-radius: 35px;
    border-top-right-radius: 35px;  
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    min-width:980px;
    border: solid 3px white;
}
#backgnd {
    background-image:url("../images/gradient-bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

}
#header {
    background-image:url('../images/header-bg.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 980px;
    height: 140px;
    border-radius: 35px;


}
h1{

    padding-left: 50px;
    color: #800000;

}
#content {
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    background-color: white;
    width: 747px;
    margin-left: 19px;
    padding-top: 5px;

}
p{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#navbar {
    background-color: white;
    width: 185px;
    margin-right: 19px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;

}
#footer{

    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

a{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: red;
}
.button {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color:#b3b3b3;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;



 }
.title{
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 78;
    padding-left: 68px;
    height: 140px;
    line-height: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.Rubrik{
    padding-left: 50px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Times New Roman;

}
```

Comment: Seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/rhjfagLh Any 404 errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<body>` no longer has an ID of `#backgnd` this has changed to `#backnd` for whatever reason, this could also be the other way around.

Change the following:

```
#backgnd {
    background-image:url("../images/gradient-bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

}
```

Into:

```
#backnd {
    background-image:url("../images/gradient-bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

}
```

and it should work as before.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yep, that's it @emil1985, a typo

Comment: @emil1985 Glad to see that it worked, please do not forget to mark this answer as the correct answer so people with the same problem can find the correct answer quickly